# Insert interactive Tableau visualization into Powerpoint

Tags: mapping, powerpoint, tableau-desktop

Objective: Insert interactive Tableau Map Visual (from Tableau Public) into Powerpoint

Issue: Data viz not showing.

Here is my process:

Click the 'Share' icon in the top right of data viz -> Copy Link (not the Embed Code) -> Go to Powerpoint -> Webviewer -> Paste Link -> Delete the extra http:// -> Preview

No preview shows and all I see on the bottom right of my Webviewer is the  button. I tried enlarging the Webviewer by expanding the corners or by going into 'Presentation Mode'. No luck.

Is this a permissions issue? Why can't I see my data viz?

I have also tried to use the link in my URL so I used the same process as above but just copied the actual URL into the Webviewer also no luck.

Link to my question on Tableau Community Page https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T0000154LpFSAU/inserting-tableau-interactive-map-into-powerpoint

Link to Loom Video illustrating my issue:

https://www.loom.com/share/e5dc87a5f3f1443ba5460d7b0c9587c4